# JSON Decode decodes only part of the JSON string?

Tags: php, json, curl

When I'm trying to decode the JSON string to the array, it decodes only one entry from the entire string.

```
    public function GetAllCommunities() {
        $json_url = "URL";
        $json_name = "NAME";

        $returnArray = null;

        $curl_init = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
        $result = curl_exec($curl_init);
        curl_close($curl_init);

        //print_r($result);

        $jsonArray2 = json_decode($result, true);

        print_r($jsonArray2);
    }
```

When I `print_r` the `result`, I get all the data, but when I do decode the `json_decode($result, true);`, I get only 1 entry from the entire feed.

Any idea why? Could this mean there's error in the feed?

I have nested JSONs there, and I'm checking their correctness by using this: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have duplicate entries. In your JSON string, you have `Community` repeated several times. Check here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed. You have several objects on the same level with the same name (`Comnunity`).

Instead of

```
[
    {
        Comunity: ... ,
        Comunity: ... ,
        Comunity: ... ,
    }
]
```

Do:

```
[
    {
        Comunity: ... 
    },
    {
        Comunity: ...
    },
    {
        Comunity: ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you much. I would never catch this one haha

Comment: There are several possible ways, but the one he tries is def not working :D

Comment: @scragar: I think he's getting the JSON structure from an **external** feed, so he probably wouldn't be able to edit the structure :p

Comment: I don't construct the feed, I'm just using it. thanks anyways.